# NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILabel view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffbd0da2680'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Below is the code where i get this error.

```
UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, self.view.bounds.size.height - 44.0f, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44.0f)];
    toolBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    [self.view addSubview:toolBar];    
    UIBarButtonItem *people = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"people" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(tap:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *food = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"food" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(tap:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *nature = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"nature" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(tap:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *sports = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"sports" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(tap:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *cats = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"cats" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(tap:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil]; 
    UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [lbl1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0,5,100,20)];
    lbl1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    lbl1.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    lbl1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [self.view addSubview:lbl1];
    lbl1.text= @"TEST";
    [toolBar setItems:@[space, lbl1, people, food, nature, sports, cats, space]];
```

Comment: why are adding label on toolbar?

Comment: i want to display a text apart from the barbutton item. thats the reason...

Comment: Add it above or below not on the toolbar itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in this line because you add label in toolBar. Use this code

```
UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, self.view.bounds.size.height - 44.0f, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44.0f)];
toolBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
[self.view addSubview:toolBar];
UIBarButtonItem *people = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"people" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(tap:)];
UIBarButtonItem *food = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"food" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(tap:)];
UIBarButtonItem *nature = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"nature" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(tap:)];
UIBarButtonItem *sports = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"sports" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(tap:)];
UIBarButtonItem *cats = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"cats" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(tap:)];
UIBarButtonItem *space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[lbl1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0,64,100,20)];
lbl1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
lbl1.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
lbl1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[self.view addSubview:lbl1];
lbl1.text= @"TEST";
[toolBar setItems:@[space, people, food, nature, sports, cats, space]];
```

toolBar item clicked event

```
-(IBAction)tap:(UIBarButtonItem*)sender{
    lbl1.text= sender.title;
}
```

Comment: yes. if the barbutton item alone is present, it works fine. But i also need to display a text along with the barbutton items.

Comment: You Change your label text color because current textColor is White so not display. @vig

Comment: try this `lbl1.textColor=[UIColor redColor];` and also change this [lbl1 `setFrame:CGRectMake(0,64,100,20)];` @vig

Comment: you use this `[toolBar setItems:@[space, people, food, nature, sports, cats, space]];` ? @vig

Comment: it will work if i remove the UILabel. But i need it.

Comment: It was useful but still i need help. If u have any idea on this, it would be an help for you.

Comment: please add your output photos for more understanding. @vig